# Why two calls to @@rowcount returns two different values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this stored procedure to save values across two tables ACDPrograms and DefaultCourses. Here is my global parameters

```
 create proc USPSvUpdtACDProgramFromTypes
    @pPRGCode char(10), 
    @pPRGName varchar(100), 
    @pPRGDescr varchar(max), 
    @pFCTID int, 
    @pMinCredits int, 
    @pNZQA int, 
    @pNoOccrPerYear int,
    @pFirstMonthOccr int, 
    @pSecondMonthOccr int, 
    @pDOMFee decimal(16,2),
    @pINTLFee decimal(16,2),
    @pIsAval int, 
    @pEmpID int, 
    @pSelCRSInfo as dbo.SelectedCourses READONLY,
    @pPRGID int output  
 as
 begin
```

As you can see there is User defined table type SelectedCourses that has the following structure

```
create type dbo.SelectedCourses
as table
(
    CntrNo int not null IDENTITY(1, 1), 
    CRSID int,
    YearNo int,
    IsCompulsory int,
    EntDT datetime,
    IsAval int,
    EmpID int
);
go
```

in my stored procedure there is transaction as it has two store fours rows data in defualtCourses table with one row to the ACDPrograms. My store procedure does NOT have try/catch blocks. when iterate through the loop to store four rows the iteration works like a charm but after the last iteraton outside of the loop when I tried to access the @@rowcount, when I call it twice as regular SQL statement (no loops) as

```
select 'row count' + convert(char(1), @@rowcount) -- This line prints 0 --> INCORRECT
select 'row count' + convert(char(1), @@rowcount) -- this line prints 1 --> CORRECT BUT WHY NOW
```

first call to it, prints 0 as the value which is no true worst case scenario at the second call it prints the value that it should print in the first which is 1. why it bahves like this why it print two values when it was called twice, shouldn't it print the same value event after million calls to it?

here is the loop part and surrounding of it:

```
    if @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    begin 
    set @newPRGID = @@IDENTITY;

    -- insert to DefualtCourses table           
    declare @cntr int
    declare @cntr_max int           
    declare @CRSID int
    declare @YearNo int
    declare @IsCompulsory int 
    declare @EntDT datetime
    declare @IsAval int
    declare @EmpID int          

    set @cntr = 1

    select @cntr_max = COUNT(*) from @pSelCRSInfo

    --select 'Max No rows in UDDT' + convert(char(2), @cntr_max)

    while(@cntr <= @cntr_max)
    begin 

    select 
    @CRSID=CRSID,
    @YearNo=YearNo,
    @IsCompulsory=IsCompulsory,
    @EntDT=EntDT,
    @IsAval=IsAval,
    @EmpID=EmpID 
    from @pSelCRSInfo where CntrNo=@cntr

--select @EmpID -- from @pSelCRSInfo-- where CntrNo= @cntr


    insert into DefaultCourses 
    (PRGID,CRSID,YearNo,IsCompulsory,EntDT,IsAval,EmpID)
    values (@newPRGID,@CRSID,@YearNo,@IsCompulsory,@EntDT,@IsAval,@EmpID)               

    select 'rowcount after insert' + CONVERT(char(1), @@rowcount) -- counts all four rows --> CORRECT

    if @@rowcount > 0
    begin 
    select 'counter value' + convert(varchar(12), @cntr) --prints all four iterations --> CORRECT
    set @cntr = @cntr + 1                   
    end
    else
    begin       
    rollback tran                   
    return 3
    end
    end     -- end of loop

    --select 'last counter' + CONVERT(char(2),@cntr) THIS LINE PRINTS 5 --> CORRECT

    select 'row count' + convert(char(1), @@rowcount) -- This line prints 0 --> INCORRECT
    select 'row count' + convert(char(1), @@rowcount) -- this line prints 1 --> CORRECT BUT WHY NOW

    if @@rowcount > 0
    begin 
    select 'im in commit'
    commit tran
    return 1
    end 

    end -- end of the top @@rowcount
    else
    begin 
    --select 'im in rollback'
    rollback tran
    return 3
    end
end -- end of fresh insert block
```

the values ive used to execute the store procedure

```
USE [SMSV100]
GO

--delete from ACDPrograms
--delete from DefaultCourses

DECLARE @return_value int,
        @pPRGID int
declare @crs as dbo.SelectedCourses
set @pPRGID = -1

insert into @crs (CRSID,YearNo,IsCompulsory,EntDT,IsAval,EmpID)
values (1, 1, 1, GETDATE(), 1, 1),(2, 1, 1, GETDATE(), 1, 1),(3, 2, 1, GETDATE(), 1, 1),(4, 2, 1, GETDATE(), 1, 1)

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[USPSvUpdtACDProgramFromTypes]
        @pPRGCode = N'2323',
        @pPRGName = N'sddsaada',
        @pPRGDescr = N'asdda',
        @pFCTID = 3,
        @pMinCredits = 10,
        @pNZQA = 7,
        @pNoOccrPerYear = 2,
        @pFirstMonthOccr = 2,
        @pSecondMonthOccr = 7,
        @pDOMFee = 4500,
        @pINTLFee = 45000,
        @pIsAval = 1,
        @pEmpID = 1,
        @pSelCRSInfo = @crs,
        @pPRGID = @pPRGID OUTPUT

SELECT  @pPRGID as N'@pPRGID'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

here is the screen shot of the result window
[image]

thanks

Comment: Anywhere you make a reference to `@@ROWCOUNT`, take a look at the statement immediately before that.  The value of `@@ROWCOUNT` can change with each statement in your tsql.  For instance, a DML statement will set the value of `@@ROWCOUNT` to the number of rows affected.  But a `SET` statement (and others) will set `@@ROWCOUNT` to 1.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a long question, but this seems to be the basis of it:

```
select 'row count' + convert(char(1), @@rowcount) -- This line prints 0 --> INCORRECT
select 'row count' + convert(char(1), @@rowcount) -- this line prints 1 --> CORRECT BUT WHY NOW
```

`@@rowcount` refers to the previous `select`.  The first one is converting to a one-character string.  That is a bad idea.  It will return `'*'` if the number is too big.  But, the query also succeeds, so the second returns `@@rowcount`.

I would suggest doing something like this:

```
declare @rc int;
set @rc = @@rowcount;
select 'row count' + convert(varchar(255), @rc)
```

EDIT:

Your loop need to be something like this:

```
declare @rc int;

insert into DefaultCourses(PRGID, CRSID, YearNo, IsCompulsory ,EntDT, IsAval, EmpID)
    values (@newPRGID,@CRSID,@YearNo,@IsCompulsory,@EntDT,@IsAval,@EmpID) ;

set @rc = @@rowcount;          

select 'rowcount after insert' + CONVERT(char(1), @rc) -- counts all four rows --> CORRECT

if @rc > 0
begin 
    select 'counter value' + convert(varchar(12), @cntr) --prints all four iterations --> CORRECT
    set @cntr = @cntr + 1                   
end
. . .
```

That is, copy `@@ROWCOUNT` into a variable first thing.  Then work with the copied value.

Comment: im sorry to have it too long I thought it would be  helpful as this is some what weird. anyway why did you save the value came from the first call to @@rowcount and second print the value came from the second call to @@rowcount?

Comment: @AndrewMC . . . I fixed that.

Comment: thanks your technique worked : ) 
so @@rowcount changes it value each call to it

Comment: @AndrewMC . . . It will change with each `select` (as well as other statements).

Comment: @AndrewMC . . . Put the value into a variable immediately when you want it, and then only use the variable.  You can do:  `if @@ROWCOUNT > 0`.

Comment: thank you : ) and sorry for the lengthy initial post